# How pass string separated by spaces parameter to Jenkins build trigger?

Tags: jenkins

*This works so far:*

```
http://JENKINS_SERVER/job/YOUR_JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?myparam=Hello
```

But when the **value** of `myparam` contains whitespaces  like in `Hello word` it doesn't work:

```
myparam=Hello word
```

*Full line:*

```
http://JENKINS_SERVER/job/YOUR_JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?myparam=Hello world
```

**How can I pass this parameter value?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to replace the blank space by %20 :

`http://JENKINS_SERVER/job/YOUR_JOB_NAM/buildWithParameters?myparam=Hello%20world`

This is known as **Url Enconding** used for unsafe or special characters.

This is a summary table :

```
character      encoded equivalence

backspace      %08
tab            %09
space          %20
!              %21
"              %22
#              %23
$              %24
%              %25
&              %26
'              %27
(              %28
)              %29
*              %2A
+              %2B
,              %2C
-              %2D
.              %2E
/              %2F
:              %3A
;              %3B
<              %3C
=              %3D
>              %3E
?              %3F
@              %40
[              %5B
\              %5C
]              %5D
^              %5E
_              %5F
`              %60
{              %7B
|              %7C
}              %7D
¿              %BF
```

References:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100331-00/?p=14443
- https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/
- complete url encoded values : https://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php